# No appropriate Python interpreter found Cassandra Python 3.1,3.4

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh, setenv

I've installed Cassandra 3.9 on Centos 6.7 which has Python 3.1.1 installed at /usr/local/bin/python.

When I try to start the cql shell, it says no appropriate python interpreter found. I tried installing python 3.4 and alias it. but that gives the same error.

I have a few questions on this.

1. what are the compatible Python versions that Cassandra 3.9 supports?
2. How do I change the Python version permanently from the existing version which is mounted on a read-only file system(which python) to the version I install now?(using cshell)

I echo'd the pyver variable being used. It says 2.7 which should be compatible with Cassandra 3.9 but still gives an error.

[image]

Comment: `cqlsh` I believe is python 2.7 only. I actually  tried to improve this case (and messaging) [here](https://github.com/spiside/cqlsh/commit/a880445ec9d05cfa552928d5a88d1457640456b6).

Comment: Not sure what the reason is,.., I have a python version 2.7 and I specified the interpreter to be 2.7 to run cqlsh.py but it still says i need 2.7